# ReorderableListView inside SingleChildScrollView/Column

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to put my reorderable list inside SingleChildScrollView, but the ReorderableListView() doesn't have shrink wrap like ListView(). Is there a work around to accomplish this layout without using an outdated unmaintained package? Although, I haven't tested those available outdated packages yet I don't know if they're built using different widgets or they're just building upon ReorderableListView() if so the error will persist.

Comment: did you solve this issue? thank you

Answer (score 3):

you can wrap your **ReorderableListView** with **Expanded** Widget in **Column**.

Answer (score 2):

The flutter team has released 2.0.1 stable recently, which shipped with a new designed ReorderableList class. As I tested, the ReorderableList class can work with Column and SingleChildScrollView smoothly.

code snippet like:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      ReorderableList(
              controller: ScrollController(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: itemList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final item = itemList[index];
                return ReorderableDelayedDragStartListener(
                          index: index,
                          key: UniqueKey(),
                          ListTile(...),
                        );
              },
              onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {...},
         ),
       ],
     ),
   );
```

Comment: even when copy pasting this code it does not work

Comment: please show your code here so that I can see what went wrong.

Comment: shrinkWrap did it for me

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using a Reorderable Listview inside a Column which was inside an ScrollView.

Tried multiple combinations but was getting the error, so I just wrapped each ListTile of the ListView in a container, and it worked for me. If that doesnt work then try limiting the height of each container.